# PySerial - Max baud rate for platform

Tags: python, pyserial, baud-rate

I have a Tiva LaunchPad that I have been communicating with via Python and PySerial. I just set up a new Debian box that's main function is going to be communicating with the LaunchPad's.

I was surprised to discover that the 921600kBaud rate that I have been using did not work on the new Debian box, however 230400kBaud was successful.

Is there a good way, perhaps through serial or os python calls to determine the maximum baud rate the platform can handle?

So before I opened a serial line I could determine if the baud rate was actually going to work.

Something like:

```
def baudtestfunction(b):
    # test for valid baud rate here
    [if valid baud]:
        return True
    [else invalid baud:]
        return False

if (baudtestfunction(_baud) == True):
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port     = _port,
        baudrate = _baud,
        parity   = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
    )
else:
    printf "The chosen baud rate will not work on this platform"
    exit()
```

On the Debian box if I set _baud to 921600 it appears to open the serial connection, it just doesn't send/receive data properly. I was unable to determine if it was the serial connection that wasn't working or if the Tiva itself wasn't working.

Comment: you should know the baudrate for the device you are connecting to... the only way to test it is to open up a serialport and send a command and see if you got the expected result ... this sounds like ftdi , which afaik can work at whatever baud its basically regulated by the speed of your usb bus

Comment: @JoranBeasley While that is true, I want this code to be easily transferable. If I give this to someone to run, they may not even know what a baud rate is. When they attempt to run it and get no error message, they may have no idea where it's breaking down. I get a phone call and have to run through all possible error scenarios before I can determine the Tiva is configured for a baud rate that doesn't work with the machine. My question boils down to, how can I determine the speed of the usb bus from python?